# Kubernetes exec return the mess from container

Tags: windows, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to learn Kubernetes, and always when I run `kubectl exec` there is a total mess in console:

```
$ kubectl.exe exec pod-httpd -c cntr-httpd -- ls -l
I0630 16:45:11.161801    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) (0xc000280d20) Create stream
I0630 16:45:11.170797    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) (0xc000280d20) Stream added, broadcasting: 1
I0630 16:45:11.175797    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) Reply frame received for 1
I0630 16:45:11.175797    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) (0xc000415680) Create stream
I0630 16:45:11.176798    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) (0xc000415680) Stream added, broadcasting: 3
I0630 16:45:11.177804    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) Reply frame received for 3
I0630 16:45:11.177804    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) (0xc0002da0a0) Create stream
I0630 16:45:11.177804    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) (0xc0002da0a0) Stream added, broadcasting: 5
I0630 16:45:11.179799    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) Reply frame received for 5
I0630 16:45:11.226800    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) Data frame received for 3
I0630 16:45:11.226800    1136 log.go:172] (0xc000415680) (3) Data frame handling
I0630 16:45:11.226800    1136 log.go:172] (0xc000415680) (3) Data frame sent
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  9 07:02 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  9 07:02 build
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  9 07:02 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jun  9 07:02 conf
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun  9 07:02 error
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  9 07:02 htdocs
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun  9 07:02 icons
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  9 07:02 include
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 30 14:35 logs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  9 07:02 modules
I0630 16:45:11.367590    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) Data frame received for 1
I0630 16:45:11.367590    1136 log.go:172] (0xc000280d20) (1) Data frame handling
I0630 16:45:11.367590    1136 log.go:172] (0xc000280d20) (1) Data frame sent
I0630 16:45:11.368592    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) (0xc000415680) Stream removed, broadcasting: 3
I0630 16:45:11.368592    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) (0xc000280d20) Stream removed, broadcasting: 1
I0630 16:45:11.369594    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) (0xc0002da0a0) Stream removed, broadcasting: 5
I0630 16:45:11.369594    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) Go away received
I0630 16:45:11.369594    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) (0xc000280d20) Stream removed, broadcasting: 1
I0630 16:45:11.370592    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) (0xc000415680) Stream removed, broadcasting: 3
I0630 16:45:11.370592    1136 log.go:172] (0xc0000e82c0) (0xc0002da0a0) Stream removed, broadcasting: 5
```

If I try run shell there is a lot of debugging information, which does not allow me to work comfortably

I run it on Windows.

Kubernetes version

```
$ kubectl.exe version --short
Client Version: v1.18.0
Server Version: v1.18.3
```

Any help to disabling this debug message will be appreciated.

Best regards,
Draqun

Comment: just set the env DEBUG to "", detail see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144822/disabling-network-logs-on-kubernetes-when-running-kubectl-exec

Comment: @user19485118 You're right. The problem occurs because of mess in my system, and DEBUG flag.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the default verbosity is set to something higher than `-v=0`. Also, afaik there is no option to read the verbosity from a config file as of this writing. I wonder where you downloaded your `kubectl.exe` file from.

You can run `kubectl options` to set the default global options configured.

```sh
$ kubectl.exe options
The following options can be passed to any command:
...
  -v, --v=0: number for the log level verbosity
...
```

The short term fix is just to force that option in the command line:

```sh
$ kubectl.exe -v=0 ...
```

Comment: I've kubernates installed with Docker. I also updated the kubernetes using official package. My minicube was installed via choco. So all elements should work without any weird complications.

I'll check your proposition

Comment: Sadly flag -v=0 (or other number too) does not make a change

Comment: Did you get it figured out?

Comment: Are you running on Windows? On a command prompt? Also, where did you download kubectl from?

Comment: PLatform is Windows, Kubernetes comes with docker. I tried also kubernetes from official kubernetes page but it does not change anything.

Comment: What about kubectl? where did you download it from? Did you build it from source?

Comment: No I didn't. I had no time to do it. I expected out of box solution, now I do not have time for spending it for kubernetes.

Comment: If it's out of the box, it should be fine. I was wondering where you got, maybe it was prebuilt with something specific.

Comment: It has to be some shell environment variable forcing it to output verbose.